# Javascript function on keypress (enter) if field equals

Tags: javascript, html

I need to make the enter key take the user to different url's based on the value in a specific field.
This is what I have so far

```
 <script type="text/javascript">  document.onkeyup = KeyPressed;   
     function KeyPressed( e )  {    
         var key = ( window.event ) ? event.keyCode : e.keyCode;         
         switch( key )    {      
             case 13:        
                 if (this.getField("ls").value == 'x') {
                     alert ("its x")
                     window.location="ccamntdue.html"

                 } else if (this.getField("ls").value == ' ') {
                     alert ("its not")


                 } else {



                 }   

</script>
```

I can remove the argument and get the enterkey to return an alert for testing to verify it is seeing the enter key. The problem seems to be in the argument.  I have included several alerts to test if any part of the argument is working but cannont seem to get it to work.   It has been several years since I have worked with html/Javascript and I am a little rusty.
I would like to have it verify if the field = "a"  then take the user to "A_url.html" if the field equals "b" then take the user to "b_url.html" etc. once the enter key is pressed.

Comment: you have to use window.location.href="<xxx>" if I remember correctly

Comment: @TobSpr That's incorrect, setting `location` and `location.href` to a string do the exact same thing https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location "You can also assign a string to window.location. This means that you can work with window.location as if it were a string in most cases"

Comment: What is this.getField doing? At this point in your code it looks like this = window and thus your are looking for window.getField!

Comment: @Sam Actually, `this` is the `document` object in this case since that's what the handler is attached to. But I've also never heard of a `getField` function

Comment: @user2055269 Please post some code that doesn't have syntax errors. Also what is `ls`? The name of a field? Its id? What error messages are you getting? http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using [DynaForms Objects](http://wiki.processmaker.com/index.php/JavaScript_in_DynaForms) ...

Try like below... it will help you...

```
<body onkeyup="KeyPressed(event)">

<script>
function KeyPressed(event)
{
switch(event.keyCode)
{
case 13:
    switch (getField("ls").value)
    {
     case "a":
     window.location.assign("https://www.google.com");
     break;
     case "b":
     window.location.assign("http://www.bing.com/");
     break;
     default:
     //Default Statement;
    }
break;
default:
//Default Statement;
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's something that should do it. Assuming you give your input the id of `ls` http://jsfiddle.net/GZNYc/

```
document.onkeyup = function ( e )  {
    var key = ( window.event ) ? event.keyCode : e.keyCode;
    if (key == 13) {
        var value = document.getElementById('ls').value;
        if (value === 'x') {
            window.location = "x.html";            
        } else {
            window.location = "a.html";
        }    
    }
};
```

The main problem with your code is the fact there is no `getField` method on the `document` object (which is what `this` points to in your handler). Its syntax is also invalid, but that doesn't seem to be your question.

Comment: I attempted this, and this is the error that I get:  0x800a138f - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'value': object is null or undefined.     I Have assigned the field the name "ls" as follows    <input type="text" name="ls" class="inputtext" maxlength="1"></p>

Comment: @user2055269 Did you look at http://jsfiddle.net/GZNYc/? You have to assign an id to your field. `<input type="text" id="ls" />` Says it right in my answer "Assuming you give your input the id of ls"

Comment: yes it does... sorry about that. I am in borderline burnout mode.  I am thinking I should step away to clear my head so I can focus a little better.  I will give it a try.

Comment: @downvoter Please explain the downvote so I can improve the answer